# Placing n nonattacking rooks on a n*n toroidal board

Tags: combinatorics

First thing I did was googling. Second looking into the OEIS. Strangely, nothing came up. So, what's the number of permutations $P=(p(1),p(2),\dots)$ of $n$ elements if you place rook nr. $i$ on field $i,p(i)$ on a square board, glue it to a torus and only count nonequivalent configurations? (Note that rotations and mirroring still count as nonequivalent!)

Starts with $1,1,1,\dots$

Comment: If rotations and mirroring are counted, doesn't the sequence begin $1,1,2\dots$? There are both right-handed and left-handed helix arrangements on the $3 \times 3$ torus, aren't there?

Comment: This corresponds to the sequence https://oeis.org/A002619

Comment: @Lemmon: Ah yes, correct. I can't count, am I thus a mathematician :-)))

Comment: @caduk: No wonder I couldn't find it. Feel free to upgrade to an answer - but please show why the definitions coincide ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a regular board, a configuration can be represented by a permutation, where each rook is placed at coordinates $(i, \sigma(i))$ for $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$.

When we shift the board horizontally, the equivalent configurations clearly corresponds to the set of circular permutations.

When we can shift the board vertically, we apply a circular shift to the inverse permutation, which is equivalent to apply a cyclic permutation. The equivalent configurations thus corresponds to the orbit of the cyclic group.
The problem is thus equivalent to find the number of orbits of the group action of the cyclic group.

On a toroïdal board, we thus search orbits of the cyclic group acting on the set of circular permutations.

This corresponds to the description of [A002619](https://oeis.org/A002619) (I don't know what is the meaning of a 2-colored pattern).

In the references given, [this paper](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/patterns/weaving/articles/sjea_pat.pdf) clearly match your formulation of the problem.

Comment: Neither did I (meaning of "pattern"), but the paper you linked explained it for me.